# Simple HTML Dom

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Thanks for taking the time to read my post... I'm trying to extract some information from my website using Simple HTML Dom...

I have it reading from the HTML source ok, now I'm just trying to extract the information that I need. I have a feeling I'm going about this in the wrong way... Here's my script...

```
<?php

include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

// create doctype
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");

// display document in browser as plain text
// for readability purposes
//header("Content-Type: text/plain");

// create root element
$xmlProducts = $dom->createElement("products");
$dom->appendChild($xmlProducts);

$html = file_get_html('http://myshop.com/small_houses.html');
$html .= file_get_html('http://myshop.com/medium_houses.html');
$html .= file_get_html('http://myshop.com/large_houses.html');

    //Define my variable for later
    $product['image'] = '';
    $product['title'] = '';
    $product['description'] = '';

foreach($html->find('img') as $src){

    if (strpos($src->src,"http://myshop.com") === false) {
        $src->src = "http://myshop.com/$src->src";
    }
       $product['image'] = $src->src;
}

foreach($html->find('p[class*=imAlign_left]') as $description){
       $product['description'] =  $description->innertext;
}

foreach($html->find('span[class*=fc3]') as $title){
       $product['title'] =  $title->innertext;
}

echo $product['img'];
echo $product['description'];
echo $product['title'];

?>
```

I put echo's on the end for sake of testing...but I'm not getting anything... Any pointers would be a great HELP!

Thanks

Charles

Comment: You cannot concatenate DOM document elements. Put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of the file to see which errors you get.

Comment: Great stuff that could be it! Thanks Felix I'll give it a go

Comment: that will not fix your issue, it will just display errors that your code is causing, also @Felix King: I think that the __toString method is within HTMLDom, so it can concatenate, but then he is trying to loop an string as an object.

Comment: @RobertPitt: Yes what I meant is that he would get the desired result if he concatenates them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`file_get_html()` returns a HTMLDom Object, and you cannot concatenate Objects, although HTMLDom have __toString methods when there concatenated there more then lilly corrupt in some way, try the following:

```
<?php

include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

// create doctype
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");

// display document in browser as plain text
// for readability purposes
//header("Content-Type: text/plain");

// create root element
$xmlProducts = $dom->createElement("products");
$dom->appendChild($xmlProducts);

$pages = array(
    'http://myshop.com/small_houses.html',
    'http://myshop.com/medium_houses.html',
    'http://myshop.com/large_houses.html'
)


foreach($pages as $page)
{
    $product = array();
    $source = file_get_html($page);

    foreach($source->find('img') as $src)
    {
        if (strpos($src->src,"http://myshop.com") === false)
        {
            $product['image'] = "http://myshop.com/$src->src";
        }
    }

    foreach($source->find('p[class*=imAlign_left]') as $description)
    {
        $product['description'] =  $description->innertext;
    }

    foreach($source->find('span[class*=fc3]') as $title)
    {
        $product['title'] =  $title->innertext;
    }

    //debug perposes!

    echo "Current Page: " . $page . "\n";
    print_r($product);
    echo "\n\n\n"; //Clear seperator
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for that Robert, much better way of doing it! However its still has an error somewhere? no errors just a blank screen...?

Comment: SWEEEEET it was just a ; missing from $pages = array(
    ...
)